# Make the compiler ignore \underline command

Tags: underline

I have the command `\underline` in several parts of my document. I would like to check how it looks without any underlining. But I don't want to recover all the instances of the `\underline` command in case I change my mind.

How can I achieve this?
Instructing the compiler to ignore all instances of a command would work, I guess? But I don't know how to.

I use the Overleaf platform.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you run

```
\renewcommand\underline[1]{#1}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\underline{abcde}$

\renewcommand\underline[1]{#1}
$\underline{abcde}$
\end{document}
```